# How to migrate custom index configuration from Solr to Azure Cognitive Search?

Tags: azure-search

I am trying to switch from Solr to Azure Cognitive Search in Sitecore 9.1, but for some reason my fields are not shown in custom index after migration.

Solr custom index configuration:

```xml
<customIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration">
    <initializeOnAdd>false</initializeOnAdd>

    <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap" >
        <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
            <typeMatch typeName="guidCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
        </typeMatches>

        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
            <field fieldName="category" returnType="guidCollection" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"/>
            <field fieldName="entry_date" returnType="text" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="2f" type="System.String"/>
        </fieldNames>
    </fieldMap>
    <fieldReaders ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldReaders"/>

    <documentOptions ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/documentOptions" >
        <include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
            <Custom_Item>{FD160A2F-CB96-4751-A777-0E289035D61B}</Custom_Item>
        </include>
        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
            <patch:delete />
        </exclude>
    </documentOptions>

</customIndexConfiguration>
```

Category is Multilist field of Custom_Item in sitecore, Entry Date is Datetime field of Custom_Item.

Updated Azure Custom Index config:

```xml
<customIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration">
    <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>

    <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration/fieldMap" >
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
            <field fieldName="category" boost="1f" type="System.Guid[]" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
            <field fieldName="entry_date" boost="2f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
        </fieldNames>
    </fieldMap>
                    
    <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch" >
        <include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
            <Custom_Item>{FD160A2F-CB96-4751-A777-0E289035D61B}</Custom_Item>
        </include>
        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
            <patch:delete />
        </exclude>
    </documentOptions>
                    
</customIndexConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue. All changes are marked with comment sections. Correct index configuration is:

```xml
<customIndexConfiguration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration">
    <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>

    <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultCloudIndexConfiguration/fieldMap" >
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
            <!-- Configuration of fields was updated -->
            <field fieldName="category" cloudFieldName="category_sm" searchable="YES"  retrievable="YES"  facetable="YES"  filterable="YES"  sortable="NO" boost="1f" type="System.GUID[]" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
            <field fieldName="entry_date" cloudFieldName="entry_date_dt" boost="2f" type="System.DateTime" format="yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ" searchable="YES"  retrievable="YES"  facetable="YES"  filterable="YES"  sortable="YES" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
        </fieldNames>
    </fieldMap>
                    
    <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch" >
        <!-- Indexing of all fields was disabled -->
        <indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>
        <include hint="list:AddIncludedField">
            <Custom_Item>{FD160A2F-CB96-4751-A777-0E289035D61B}</Custom_Item>
            <!-- Fields were added here -->
            <Category>{5B96A84A-98BE-4E24-A2B0-0754500D027C}</Category>
            <Entry_Date>{430D661D-01E4-4D6D-A2E0-7EA0B2653A9D}</Entry_Date>
        </include>
        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
            <patch:delete />
        </exclude>
    </documentOptions>
                    
</customIndexConfiguration>
```